# Facebook Javascript SDK extend access token get "Invalid OAuth access token" - 190 - "OAuthException"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I try to use javacript SDK to get access token and then extend that access token for 60 day. I got reponse error like this from response: `Object { message="Invalid OAuth access token.", type="OAuthException", code=190}`

My expectation:

1. Get new access token with 60 days expire
2. Console to screen.

My Code:

```
window.onload = function() {

var isLogin = true;

FB.init({appId:422642254433770, cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true });

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and connected to your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user’s ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        var accessTokenOld = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        //Extend access token                    
        var OauthParams = {};
        OauthParams['client_id'] = '//REMOVED APP ID';
        OauthParams['client_secret'] = '//REMOVED APP SECRET';
        OauthParams['grant_type'] = 'fb_exchange_token';
        OauthParams['fb_exchange_token'] = 'accessToken';
        OauthParams['response_type'] = 'token';

        console.log("Old accessToken => " + accessToken);
        FB.api('/oauth/access_token', 'post', OauthParams, function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log(response.accesstoken);
            } else {
                console.log("Lay new access token bi loi " + response.error.message);
            }
        });        
    }
});
};
```

I try to search every where for this trouble 3 days without any clue. I there any one have experience? please help.

Many thanks

Comment: When you put the token you're trying to exchange in to [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) does it validate correctly?

Comment: Yeap Lgy, I test return token and got expire next 2 hours. There is no problem with return token, so I don't know why this error happen.

Comment: My bad: OOauthParams['fb_exchange_token'] = 'accessToken';
This will work: OOauthParams['fb_exchange_token'] = accessToken;

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in a client is a bad idea because of the requirement to include the app secret in the actual client, which is very dangerous. It's best to call a endpoint on your server that handles this separately so that app secret stays in your controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

If in Advanced Settings of your FB App you have 'Remove offline_access permission' enabled, all your access tokens will be 60 days by default.

We ran into this same issue recently and this fixed the problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

I found a simple solution to get extended access token using Jquery valide upto 2 months

**Variables to pass to the URL:**

```
var accessToken = 'CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN';
var appid       = 'APPID';
var appsecret   = 'APPSECRET';
```

**Your URL should point to**

```
var exchangeUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+accessToken+"&client_id="+appid+"&client_secret="+appsecret;
```

**Make an Ajax request as**

```
$.ajax({  
type: "GET",
url: exchangeUrl,  
success: function(data)
{ 
   extended = data.split('=');
   extendedAT = extended['1'].replace('&expires','');
       alert(extendedAT);

}

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass app secret on front scripts... is not secure