# How to receive return extend access token by javascript

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

After extend, I can:

1. See extend access token on browser:
   access_token=TOKEN&expires=EXPIRES
2. Error message "invalid assignment left-hand side"

How can I get token from response.

My Code:

---

```
<script>
      window.onload = function() {

            FB.init({appId:422642254433770, cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var accessTokenOld = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                //Extend access token                    
                var OauthParams = {};
                OauthParams['client_id'] = 'CLIEN ID';
                OauthParams['client_secret'] = 'CLIENT SECRET';
                OauthParams['grant_type'] = 'fb_exchange_token';
                OauthParams['fb_exchange_token'] = accessToken;
                OauthParams['response_type'] = 'token';

                FB.api('/oauth/access_token', 'post', OauthParams, function(extendResponse) {
                    console.log("Extend token: " + extendResponse.accessToken);
                });  
            });
        };

</script>
```

Comment: Getting an extended token requires sending the app secret, and so should never be attempted at the client-side. That said maybe this question will be of help: [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123444/facebook-javascript-sdk-extend-access-token-get-invalid-oauth-access-token-1)

Comment: Thanks Lee Sibbald this is help: "Getting an extended token requires sending the app secret, and so should never be attempted at the client-side. "